# Salesforce remove Auto Fill for an <ui:inputText>

Tags: lightning, autocomplete

I have a scenario that needs to remove the AutoFill and paste from `<ui:inputText>`. I was able to achieve restricting paste by adding "onpaste" event inside a `<a>` tag wrapping `<ui:inputText>`. Anyhow, I could not find a way to achieve restrictions for AutoFill. Below is the code that needs to get autocomplete off.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" oncontextmenu="{!c.handleContext}" onpaste="{! c.preventDefault }" > 
                                        
<ui:inputText maxlength="20" placeholder="0000000000" aura:id="accountNumberConfirm" label="Confirm Account" class="generalInputForm testScript_accountHolderNameInput"   required="true"/>
                                   
</a>
```

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to directly swap in a modern `lwc` `lightning-input` component here.

The reason for doing this, other than this component is no deprecated, is that you can set `autocomplete="off"` on the component.

Try something like:

```
<lightning:input autocomplete="off"
                 maxlength="20" 
                 placeholder="0000000000" 
                 label="Confirm Account"
                 aura:id="accountNumberConfirm" 
                 class="generalInputForm testScript_accountHolderNameInput"   
                 required="true">
</lightning:input>
```